# Probabilidad con Scipy. Problema de almuerzo en un restaurante

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter, scipy

Queremos resolver con Scipy, el siguiente problema de probabilidad.

Un restaurante ofrece un almuerzo en que se pueden elegir 2 entradas, 3 platos de fondo y 5 postres. Si no me gustan 2 de los platos de fondo y 3 de los postres. ¿Cuál es la probabilidad de que me toque un menú de mi agrado si la elección es el azar?.

Sabemos que, todo menú se compone de 1 entrada, 1 plato de fondo y 1 postre y la composición de cada uno de estos es independiente de los otros.
Denominamos las probabilidades de obtener entrada, fondo y postre de mi agrado, con **P(entrada)**, **P(fondo)** y **P(postre)** respectivamente.

En la siguiente expresión consideramos en los numeradores solo los casos favorables que sean del agrado, mientras que en los denominadores,a la cantidad total de posibilidades de componerlos. Así, la probabilidad de obtener un menú de mi agrado es:

P(entrada) x P(plato de fondo) x P(postre) = (2/2) x (3-2)/3 x (5-3)/5 = 1 x (1/3) x (2/5) = 2/15.

Para intentar resoverlo con Scipy hacemos lo siguiente.

```
from scipy.special import comb

# Número de opciones para cada categoría
num_entradas = 2
num_platos_fondo = 3
num_postres = 5

# Número de opciones que no te gustan
platos_fondo_no_gustan = 2
postres_no_gustan = 3

# Calcular el número total de combinaciones posibles
total_combinaciones = comb(num_entradas, 2) * comb(num_platos_fondo, 3) * comb(num_postres, 5)

# Calcular el número de combinaciones favorables
combinaciones_favorables = comb(num_entradas, 2) * comb(num_platos_fondo - platos_fondo_no_gustan, 1) * comb(num_postres - postres_no_gustan, 2)

# Calcular la probabilidad
probabilidad = combinaciones_favorables / total_combinaciones

print("La probabilidad de que te toque un menú de tu agrado es:", probabilidad)
```

Devuelve 'La probabilidad de que me toque un menú de mi agrado es: 1.0
', lo cual no coincide con el cálculo clásico razonado al principio.

¿Cuál es el fallo?.Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

El problema está en la forma en que utilizas [`scipy.special.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html) y la forma en que ingresas los datos.

En primer lugar, el enunciado dice:

> Sabemos que, todo menú se compone de 1 entrada, 1 plato de fondo y 1 postre

Los argumentos de `comb` son:

```
N: int, ndarray
   Número de objetos/cosas

k: int, ndarray
   Número de objetos/cosas que se toman.
```

Por lo tanto, `k` para todas las instancias de `comb` es `1` porque siempre se obtiene un elemento de las opciones que haya para cada categoría.

Si agregamos unos `print` para ver el `total_combinaciones` y `combinaciones_favorables` vas a ver que al ingresar los argumentos correctos el número total de combinaciones es `30` y el número de opciones favorables es de `4`. Por lo que el resultado es `0.133` tal como lo mencionas en la pregunta.

Ejemplo completo:

```
from scipy.special import comb

# Número de opciones para cada categoría
num_entradas = 2
num_platos_fondo = 3
num_postres = 5

# Número de opciones que no te gustan
platos_fondo_no_gustan = 2
postres_no_gustan = 3

# Calcular el número total de combinaciones posibles
# total_combinaciones = comb(num_entradas, 2) * comb(num_platos_fondo, 3) * comb(num_postres, 5)
total_combinaciones = comb(num_entradas, 1) * comb(num_platos_fondo, 1) * comb(num_postres, 1)
print(total_combinaciones)

# Calcular el número de combinaciones favorables
# combinaciones_favorables = comb(num_entradas, 2) * comb(num_platos_fondo - platos_fondo_no_gustan, 1) * comb(num_postres - postres_no_gustan, 2)
combinaciones_favorables = comb(num_entradas, 1) * comb(num_platos_fondo - platos_fondo_no_gustan, 1) * comb(num_postres - postres_no_gustan, 1)
print(combinaciones_favorables)

# Calcular la probabilidad
probabilidad = combinaciones_favorables / total_combinaciones

print("La probabilidad de que te toque un menú de tu agrado es:", probabilidad)
```

Esto imprime:

```
30.0
4.0
La probabilidad de que te toque un menú de tu agrado es: 0.13333333333333333
```